# what does initValidation.validate mean?

Tags: javascript

why are we calling `initValidation()` and where is `initValidation.validate` stored ?

```js
    function initValidation()
    {
        // irrelevant code here
        function validate(_block){
            console.log( "test", _block );
        }
    
        initValidation.validate = validate;
    }

    initValidation();
    initValidation.validate( "hello" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this snippet you are doing this:

1. declaring a function called `initValidation`
2. calling the function `initValidation` that, when called, add to its definition the `validate` function, that is declared inside the function itself
3. after the initialization, you call the `validate` function that, at this point, is defined as part of `initValidation`

Comment: thanks! i don't understand why should I add initValidation.validate = validate; and it doesn't work without it?

Comment: Because if you remove that line the function is only declared inside the `initValidation` but it is not part of the `initValidation` itself.